# Error while indexing nutch data to solr

Tags: linux, solr, nutch

I'm trying to index my crawl data from nutch into solr and I recieve the following error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SOLRIndexWriter
solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance (mandatory)
solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
solr.auth.username : use authentication (default false)
solr.auth : username for authentication
solr.auth.password : password for authentication


Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:123)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:81)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
```

Comment: what are the contents of the logs/hadoop.log file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you see solr log?  Those logs record the error reason.
I ever had same problem in nutch  and found a message "unknown field host" in solr's log.
After I edited the scheme.xml,  the problem vanished.